# unable to capture response to a POST request to a node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, express

I am learning to use node and express. I am creating a demo site using node express and google translate API to learn the various functionalities. The issue I'm running into is that when I post data to the server to be computed and returned, the server receives the request and sends the response, but the browser does not display the result. Instead the console diplays "navigated to localhost:8080/?'. I am hosting locally.

Here's the code for the **server app:**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var settings = require('./settings');
var googleTranslate = require('google-translate')(settings.googleApiKey);

var port = 8080;
var hostname = 'localhost';
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("incoming post request");
  console.log("text to detect: " + req.body.text);

  googleTranslate.detectLanguage(req.body.text, function(err, detection) {
    console.log(detection.language);

    res.status(200);
    res.contentType('text/plain');
    res.end(detection.language);
  });
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port);
});
```

The code for the function that is supposed to make the Ajax call and display the response. This is in a file that is called from a script tag in the **index.html (get-langdetect.js):**

```
var inputField = document.querySelector('#input');
var detectOutput = document.querySelector('#langlayer-output');

var getLang = function getLang() {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    text: inputField.value
  });

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: data
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('received response!');
      return response.body;
    }
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    inputField.innerHTML = '<text>' + data + '</text>';
  });
};
```

Pertinent **index.html** code snippet:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="center-elem">
    <h1 class="center-elem">Detection</h1>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text to detect" id="input">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="getLang()">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="langlayer-output">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src='./get-langdetect.js'></script>
```

Comment: The `Navigated to` log seems irrelevant, probably gets logged by Chrome when you open the page. What happens if you remove the `if` statement in the first `then` block? Just console.log the response. Does it even have an `ok` property?

Comment: Also, if you are using Chrome, you can open up the Javascript console and click on the "Network" tab. Then submit the form, and you can see the request, as well as whether it responds, the response body, response headers, etc. This can help in troubleshooting issues like this.

Comment: @Partik the navigated to log appears every time I hit submit. The page refreshes. I tried removing the if statement and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Please see my answer below. If it solves your problem, you can select it as the answer. If not, you can comment on why it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When forms are submitted, it is expected that they either refresh the page, or navigate to the url in the `action` attribute on the `<form>`.

A quick way to avoid this is to put `return false;` after your function.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="getLang(); return false;">
    Submit
</button>
```

Here's a good read on the subject.
http://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/submitting-html-form-without-reload-the-page/

I'd recommend doing some homework on `<form>` elements and their basic usage to understand the typical behavior.